# How to insert, retrieve multiple image from database

Tags: php

this is the php code to give the path to images,
the multiple images i am getting from another ios app, how to insert the images into database with different name and display it?

```
<?php

$myparam = $_POST['userfile'];     //getting multiple image Here

//$mytextLabel= $_POST['filenames']   //getting textLabe Here
//echo $myparam;
//echo $mytextLabel;
$target_path  = "uploads/";
$target_path  = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "Success ! The file has been uploaded";
    //insert query will run here right?
   //but how to get those multiple images and save it m not getting

} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm confused. So what part are you having a problem with? The code doesn't seem to match what you appear to be asking about.

Comment: how to get multiple images and how to insert it , i am stucking here

Comment: Where is your code Ashish, which you have tried for multiple image upload? *I think you are stuck in silkboard traffic*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [class.upload.php](https://github.com/verot/class.upload.php).
This class manages file uploads for you. In short, it manages the uploaded file, and allows you to do whatever you want with the file, especially if it is an image, and as many times as you want.

It is the ideal class to quickly integrate file upload in your site. If the file is an image, you can convert, resize, crop it in many ways. You can also apply filters, add borders, text, watermarks, etc... That's all you need for a gallery script for instance. Supported formats are PNG, JPG, GIF and BMP.

This is a example class:

```
class UploadFile
{

    protected $uploadFileModel;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->uploadFileModel = new UploadFileModel();
    }

    public function insert($params)
    {
        $handle = new upload($params['file'], 'fa_IR');
        $handle->file_max_size = '20000000';
        $handle->allowed = array(
            'image/png',
            'image/jpeg',
            'image/gif');
        $handle->mime_check = TRUE;
        if ($handle->uploaded) {
            $handle->process($params['file_path']);
            if ($handle->processed) {
                $params['file_name'] = $handle->file_dst_name;
                // insertToDB is a function that insert data to database
                $insToDB = $this->insertToDB(array(
                    'title' => $params['title'],
                    'file_name' => $params['file_name'],
                    'path' => $params['path'],
                    'created_at' => $params['created_at']
                ));
                if ($insToDB !== FALSE) {
                    return intval($insToDB);
                } else {
                    unlink($params['file_path'] . $params['file_name']);
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }
        }
        return $handle->error;
    }

    public function insertToDB($params)
    {
        return $this->uploadFileModel->insert($params);
    }

    public function showForm()
    {
        $str = '<input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload">';
        return $str;
    }
}
```

This is Model:

```
public function insert($params)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO `upload` ( `title`, `file_name`, `path`, `status`, `created_at`, `updated_at` )
              VALUES( :title, :file_name, :path, :status, :created_at, :updated_at )";
    try{
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':file_name', $file_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':path', $path, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':created_at', $created_at, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':updated_at', $updated_at, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        extract($params);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $this->pdo->lastInsertId();
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Mohammad, How you knew he is having MVC Structure in his project ?

Comment: Oh yes... i'am sorry, but it' is a answer and you cat do it without MVC by writing it's functions.

Answer (score 0):

Since, not much data/code provided by Ashish. I'm assuming from my side.

**ImageUpload.php**

Firstly, You need to have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to upload image. 
Secondly, you need to declare `name` as array type. (Since you are uploading multiple image)

```
<form action="SubmitImageUpload.php" method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type='file' name='userfile[]' multiple>
    <input type='submit' value="Submit Image">
</form>
```

**SubmitImageUpload.php**

```
<?
extract($_POST);
// This will count total images selected.
$TotalImage = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

for($i = 0;$i<$TotalImage;$i++)
{ 
  $image_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
    $target_path = "uploads/".$imagename;

  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path))
  {
    //Write Query Here To Insert Into Database
  }
}
?>
```

And, Since you have not given us your DB Structure So, I can't assume your DB Structure and write code for retreiving.